# Magento keep alive response: connection close

Tags: .htaccess, magento, magento-1.7, keep-alive, mod-headers

I am trying to add a KeepAlive statement to my htaccess. I've set it like this:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>  Header set Connection keep-alive </IfModule>
```

I i tested this, I got the response close on the connection!

Does someone know how to resolve this? 
I am on magento 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

For those who search for an answer:

KeepAlive have to be activated by your Hoster. Then you can enable it in your htaccess.